# Writing html with HTMLTextWriter in irregular order

Tags: c#, html, htmltextwriter

I generate a html page with HTMLTextWriter. At one point I do need some information, which I haven't yet. I will get them later. It is not possible to workaround and to get the information earlier.

Is there a way, how I can jump back as soon as I get the information and add the missing items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All classes that inherit from `System.IO.TextWriter` are specifically for writing a `sequential series of characters` or other information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx

So, basically no, there isn't a way to jump backwards in one of these classes.

You would likely use an `XElement` instance to create your HTML, and then use the `XElement.Save(TextWriter)` method to write it to the writer once complete.

Comment: Do you know other classes that could help me?